# Poorly formatted output in Android ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am reading from a database into a ListView with:

```
    private void showEvents(Cursor cursor) {
    ArrayList<String[]> eventsList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String[] oneEvent = new String[3];
        oneEvent[1] = cursor.getString(1);
        oneEvent[2] = cursor.getString(2);
        eventsList.add(oneEvent);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String[]> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String[]>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, eventsList);
    setListAdapter(adapter); 
}
```

The output is mangled, however. For example one row is 
`Ljava.lang.String;@b1e01410`. When I pull the database from the simulator with DDMS and peek into it, the data looks fine, so this is some type of formatting error. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what `Ljava.lang.String;@b1e01410` is?

Basically its the default output for `toString()` (from `Object`), The L at the beginning indicates it's an array. Which means your issue is that the row is receiving an array not a single string and as it's a non-string object, it 'casts' it via toString.

Comment: Thanks -- can you pls suggests changes into the code to list the string, not the array? Sorry for noob question...

Comment: You have two options - ArrayList<String[]> gets changed to a ArrayList<String> or you create a custom layout for your views and override getView to display the values in your array properly